# How to check if current cat is inside an array AND IF is parent

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

I have a global called `$best_cats`

```
global $best_cats;
$best_cats =  array(8,31,51,102,217,218);
```

Now I need to check if the current cat is inside of the array AND IF current cat, is a parent cat.

I'm trying this way but is not working. What am I doing wrong and how can I do this?

```
<?php 
    $this_category = get_category($cat);
    $cat_id = $this_category->cat_ID;
    if (in_array($cat_id, $best_cats) && ($this_category->category_parent == 0 )) { ?>

    //category is inside of the array and is a parent cat

    <?php } else { ?>

    //category is not inside the array and It's not a parent either

    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: @Anant I always get `//category is inside of the array and is a parent cat` no mather what category I'm in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you forgot `global`

```
 <?php 
        global $best_cats;
        $this_category = get_category($cat);
        $cat_id = $this_category->cat_ID;
        if (in_array($cat_id, $best_cats) && ($this_category->category_parent == 0 )) {
            //category is inside of the array and is a parent cat
        } else {    
            //category is not inside the array and It's not a parent either
        }
```